# DllImport in Xamarin not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin.Android project, I am trying to call a method from a external library:

```
[DllImport("assets/libacrcloud_extr_tool.dll")]
private static extern void acr_init();
```

I placed `libacrcloud_extr_tool.dll` in my `Assets` folder. If I unzip the .apk file, I can see the dll present `assets/libacrcloud_extr_tool.dll`. I set the build action to `AndroidAsset` and set it to `Do not copy`. But when I try to call `act_init()` it throws `DLLNotFoundException`

Comment: What are the chances your dll is a Win32/Win64 dll and not compatible with Android?

Comment: That's probably it...is there any way around this? Or should I just forget it?

Comment: If that's the case it won't work without recompiling the original source somehow. Or find an Android SDK, possibly for a different lib that does the same, and link to that